# How to add subview inside main view in Swift

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift, ios8, xcode6

I need advice how to proceed.

How to slightly dim the main view and display some busy indicator, for the duration of of some action, and then remove the dimming?

In Swift language.

Thanks!

UPD: In Objective-C I use earlier something like this:

```
UIView *dimView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
dimView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
dimView.alpha = 0.5f;
dimView.tag = 1111;
dimView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[self.view addSubview:dimView];
```

How this code we can do it in Swift?

Comment: For dimming put an overlay view. For indicator use activity indicator view. What's the hard part?

Comment: For swift, translate the code into swift. What's the hard part?

Comment: have you ever read any _basics_ about _Swift_ yet? like the free book, for instance... https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html

Comment: I have no problem to translate this code to Swift. I do not know how to make the busy indicator. I'm sorry, I'm probably not correctly formulated question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Do as follows, I have checked, working fine in Swift

We have have to initialize the view with the frame and then we have to set the `.alpha` property for dim the view.

```
let testFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
var testView : UIView = UIView(frame: testFrame)
testView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
testView.alpha=0.5
self.view.addSubview(testView)
```

And `.addSubview` will add the view inside the main view.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot about UIView(frame: .....) :-)